# Unable to telnet using wireguard

Tags: networking, wireguard

[image: Wireguard Topology]

I successfully create a wireguard setup between on prem and aws ec2 host like in the picture through public ip, can ping and telnet each other, but I have issue with ec2 host accessing onprem server, its pingable but can't telnet

On prem -> wireguard server and ec2host (ping ok, telnet ok)

Wireguard peer -> wireguard server and ec2host (ping ok, telnet ok)

Wireguard server -> wireguard peer and onprem server (ping ok, telnet ok)

Ec2 host -> wireguard peer and onprem server (ping ok, **telnet NOT ok**)

This is the config of wireguard

SERVER:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 15000
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLIC_KEY
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, 192.168.0.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

PEER:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = PRIVATE_KEY
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUBLIC_KEY
Endpoint = PUBLIC_IP:15000
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32, 172.16.0.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

I use aws route table to send traffic to wireguard server from ec2 host

When I tcpdump on wireguard server, I can see the icmp packet going through, but the telnet traffic didn't go through the wireguard server, can anyone help me find whats wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue on your "WireGuard Server" -- you likely need to adjust its firewall to allow it to forward TCP port 23 (or whatever port you're using) connections from your "EC2 Host" to your "WireGuard Peer" (including that the EC2 security group of the "WireGuard Server" needs to allow TCP port 23 connections from the "EC2 Host").